# Python - Programa de analise numeros

Tags: python

Vamos lá! Estou tentando fazer um exercício de um programa, onde o usuário irá dar a quantidade de numeros que ele deseja para serem verificados, quais são os números, e se ele quer o maior ou menor, número entre eles.
PROBLEMA: Não estou conseguindo fazer com que o input dado no escolhaUser seja lido para uma tomada de decisão do programa;

```
print ('------------------------------------------------------------')
print ('               PROGRAMA Avaliação numero                    ')
print ('------------------------------------------------------------')

quantidade_num = input ('Quantos serão os números a serem avaliados? ')
lista_numero = []

i = 1
while i <= int (quantidade_num):
    numero_input = input ('Número #' + str(i) + ' ')
    lista_numero.append(numero_input)
    i += 1

escolhaUser = input('Quer o menor ou o maior número? ')

if escolhaUser == 'maior':
    escolhaUser = True
else:
    escolhaUser = False

def maior(colecao):
    maior_item = colecao[0]
    for item in lista_numero:
        if item > maior_item:
            maior_item = item
    return maior_item

def menor(colecao):
    menor_item = colecao[0]
    for item in lista_numero:
        if item < menor_item:
            menor_item = item
    return menor_item

if escolhaUser == True:
    decisao = maior(lista_numero)
else:
    decisao = menor(lista_numero)

print (str(decisao(lista_numero)))
```

TypeError: 'str' object is no callable

Comment: A pergunta é formatada com [markdown](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Onde está `print(str(decisao(lista_numero)))` troque por `print(decisao)`

Comment: Outra coisa o python possui a funções nativas [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#min) e [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#max) que tornam desnecessárias suas funções `maior()` e `menor()`.

Answer (score 2):

Basta você alterar a 'última linha do código' que seu problema será resolvido.

troque

```
print(str(decisao(lista_numero)))
```

por:

```
print(decisao)
```

Pronto!

É um simples problema de sintaxe. Você não criou o método `decisao` para chamá-lo através da forma `decisao()`. Você apenas criou a opção `decisao` e já indicou através dos `if` no seu programa qual será a decisão do user se vai ser o "maior" ou "menor"